# Case statement with division

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have case statement below as

```
count(CASE WHEN time_lag / 10000 >= 0 AND time_lag / 1000 <= 50 THEN 1 END) AS [0 - 50]
```

but am getting error on syntax error, is there proper way to divide in case statement? thanks

Comment: This aliasing `AS [0 - 50]` may be the problem. can you pls alias with some string - like `count(CASE WHEN time_lag / 10000 >= 0 AND time_lag / 1000 <= 50 THEN 1 END) AS group_0_to_50`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes to the desired column name (if it's not going to follow traditional naming rules.

Change:

```sql
   select count(...) AS [0 - 50]
```

To:

```sql
   select count(...) AS "[0 - 50]"
```

Btw, the exact syntax error you got was `Syntax error: unexpected '['. (line 7)`. Please make sure to include the exact error you get in future posts.

Answer (score 1):

Idenfitifers containing special characters have to be quoted with `"`. The query could be further simplified by using [COUNT_IF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count_if.html):

```
select count_if(time_lag / 10000 >= 0 AND time_lag / 1000 <= 50) AS "[0 - 50]"

=>

select count_if(time_lag/1000 BETWEEN 0 AND 50) AS "[0 - 50]"

=>
-- no epxression on the column
select count_if(time_lag BETWEEN 0 AND 50*1000) AS "[0 - 50]"
```